# Changing AssemblyVersion Stop project Compiling

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, assemblyversions

Having a very odd error when compiling me solution.

I have a solution with about 19 projects, we control the AssemblyVersion, and AssemblyFileVersion using a shared AssemblyInfo.cs this keeps all our version inline when building a release. This has worked fine for the past two years, but today I have changed both the AssemblyVersion, and AssemblyFileVersion and one project had started giving me the following error

```
delete [DLL Obj Folder Path] Access to the path '[DLL Obj Folder Path]' is denied. [DLL Obj Folder Path]
```

If we only change the AssemblyFileVersion then the project will compile.

Cant find anything on this, thanks for any help.

Edit:

Just to add a bit more info I have looked in the build output and we get the following

```
6>MSBUILD : OpenAccess Enhancer warning 0: Could not copy back original file. Access to the path '[DLL Obj Folder Path]' is denied.
6>[DLL Obj Folder Path](-1,-1): OpenAccess Enhancer error 0: delete [DLL Obj Folder Path] Access to the path '[DLL Obj Folder Path]' is denied.
```

Comment: Sounds like that file is in use. Sure you don't have any processes (started for testing purposes maybe) using that file?

Comment: No, this is happening on 4 different computers and if i leave the AssemblyVersion on its current version It will compile change that and it errors

Comment: Do you have any pre/post build events? If so, what do they do?

Comment: Nope there are no build events

Answer (score 0):

Ok Managed to fix this by recreating the project.

Created a new projected, Added all the classes using Add Existing Items, Compiled all works.
I have then added the new project by into the main solution replacing the old project and all compiles fine.

No Idea what caused the issue but I'm glad we have now got rid of the problem

Thanks